# Python : How to write class in class

Tags: python, class

How could I modify the class Auto, to make sure the **main** work?

```
class Tool:
       def __init__(self, target):
       self.target = target

    class Wifi:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        def connect(self, id):
            print id
            self.target.write("xxxxxxxxx")

        def verify(self)
            pass

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        T = Tool(target)
        T.Wifi.connect("dev")
```

I want to imitate the module like redmine:

```
from redmine import Redmine
redmine = Redmine(REDMINE_URL, key = REDMINE_API_KEY)
redmine.issue.get('16520')
```

Comment: You have poorly designed your question please reframe it.

Comment: `redmine.issue.get` means that the `issue` attribute is an object; not that there's a `class Issue` within `class Redmine`.

Comment: I've always thought there is no benefit at all to write a class in another class' body. Why not write it at module level?

Comment: @deceze  You are right!!!! 

My train of thought is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not done with nested classes but with composition:

```
class Tool:
   def __init__(self, target):
       self.target = target
       self.wifi = Wifi(self.target)

class Wifi:
    def __init__(self, target):
        self.target = target

    def connect(self, id):
        print id
        self.target.write("xxxxxxxxx")

    def verify(self)
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    T = Tool(target)
    T.wifi.connect("dev")
```

Comment: @xixiaocheng you're welcome - and feel free to accept my answer if it solved your problem ;)